# simulation of the backscattered laser pulse through clouds

Tags: physics, lidar

I want to simulate light pulse propagation through clouds and its back-scattered laser pulse waveform using the Monte Carlo methods. I am able to simulate propagation but my problem is how to simulate the detected waveform of the laser pulse.  Laser and detector are located at $z=0$ in a cloud environment,  my problem is how to program the trace of the photons that are detected by the detector. It is worth mentioning that  Henyey-Greenstein scattering function is used in simulation. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to simulate returned intensity as function of time using MATLAB software and Monte Carlo method.

Comment: You're talking about doing spherical radiative transform and recovering a waveform. This is nontrivial to say the least, even if the composition of the clouds is uniform and you have a theoretically perfect detector....

Answer (score 1):

Simulating radiative transfers is a non trivial task. There is a software named DART developed by a team from Cesbio at Paul Sabatier University in France. They are working on it for **more than a decade** and it is a very advanced tool that is capable of (among other) simulating laser beam travel in material with known properties. But this software is hardly usable without a formation with the development team (they offer free formations)

- [DART](https://dart.omp.eu/#/)